# Indexes for mongodb

Tags: performance, mongodb, indexing

I have a mongo db collection for restaurants. 
e.g.
{_id: uniquemongoid,
rank: 3,
city: 'Berlin'
}

1. Restaurants are listed by city and ordered by rank (an integer) - should I create an index on city and rank, or city/rank compound? (I query by city and sort by rank)
2. Furthermore there are several fields with booleans e.g. { hasParking:true, familyFriendly:true } - should I create indexes to speed up queries for these filters? compound indexes? Its not clear for me if I should create compound indexes as the queries can have only one boolean set or more booleans set.

Comment: It all depends how much data you have and what your queries are.

Comment: Note that you can use the [`explain()` method of cursor](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) to check which index was used to fulfill a query. So when you aren't sure if a given index helps a specific query, you can try it out and check.

Comment: My coworker gave a talk on this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AVNjqgf7zNw  He uses mysql as an example but the same principles apply. Maybe it will help you design your indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) create index { restaurant:1, rank: 1} which will serve your purpose.

You will avoid 2 indexes

2) Create a document in following format and you can query for any no of fields you want.

```
{
    info: [{hasParking:true}, {familyFriendly:true}],
    _id:
    rank:
    city:
}
db.restaurants.ensureIndex({info : 1});
db.restaurants.find({ info :{ hasParking:true}})
```

- Note MongoDB don't use two index for the same query (except $or queries). So, in the (2) case, if you want to add addition filter over the (1) query, then this (2) option won't work. I am not sure of your (2) requirement, so posting this solution.

Comment: the queries will have city,rank,booleans should I create an index with all of them? Ill have more queries with only city,rank should I create 2 indexes?

Comment: I won't recommend you for `{ city:1, rank:-1, info:1 }` because the index size will be huge. Also I am doubtful if this index can be effectively used for getting sorted result data (check `scanAndOrder` in the `explain()`). Regarding 2nd query, if I understood correctly it won't work because mongo will never use two indexes for a single query i.e `{ info:1 }` and `{ city:1, rank:-1 }`
If you are fine with the index size, you can go with the first approach.

Comment: Ill have around 10k restaurants, and I think Ill go with the first approach for now. but as we have frequent updates (to the rank) this might become a problem (beside the index size), right?

Comment: Every update because of update in ranking will cause a index update. For 10k, there won't be any issue, assuming index will always fit in the RAM.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe u want to update the 1) to rank:-1 and 2) first approach

Comment: Also, I will suggest you to always run `explain()` at development stage, to make sure that query-optimizer is using the indexes efficiently.

Comment: One more detail. the info property is an array of subdocuments? could I use a subdocument instead with the same effect of the index? "test" array with documents: "info":[
        {
                "sub1" : "val1"
        },
        {
                "sub2" : "val2"
        }
] OR subdocument: "test" : {
                "sub1" : "val1", "sub2" : "val2"
        }

Comment: no, you can not. This indexing with the second case has a entirely different behavior

Answer (score 6):

The best way to figure out whether you need indexes is to benchmark it with "explain()".

As for your suggested indexes:

1. You will need the city/rank compound index. Indexes in MongoDB can only be used for left-to-right (at the moment) and hence doing an equality search on "city" and then sorting the result by "rank" will mean that the `{ city: 1, rank: -1 }` index would work best.
2. Indexes on boolean fields are often not very useful, as on average MongoDB will still need to access half of your documents. After doing a selection by city (and hopefully a limit!) doing an extra filter for hasParking etc will *not* make MongoDB use both the city/rank and the hasParking index. MongoDB can only use one index per query.

Comment: for 2) would you agree with Abhishek Kumar to create a field holding all booleans and create an index on it?

Comment: No, as the amount of index elements is still going to be really low.